# python execute list and list of functions

Tags: python, string, function, python-2.7, maya

I'm utilizing Python 2.7 with Autodesk Maya. Here's an example of my issue:

```
import maya.cmds as m

def a(passedString):
    print('this'+passedString)
def b(passedString):
    print('that'+passedString)
def c(passedString):
    print('notThis'+passedString)
def d(passedString):
    print('ofCourse'+passedString)
string1 = [a(),b(),c(),d()]
string2 = [poly1,poly2,poly3,poly4]
for each in string2 and every in string1:
    m.select(each)
    every(each)
```

This might seem straight forward, but what I need is to have `string2[0]` (a function) executed with `string1[0]` **and only** `string1[0]`.

Same goes for the next array item. `[1]` **with** `[1]` and `[2]` **with** `[2]` and `[3]` **with** `[3]`.

Essentially, I'm trying to cut down on code and simplify how my code executes, as opposed to tediously writing the above code for 20+ individual instances.

Comment: You probably want to do: `string1 = [a,b,c,d]`

Comment: Duly noted, Alfasin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `zip` the lists to iterate through them in an element-wise fashion

```
for func, param in zip(string1, string2):
    func(param)
```

For example

```
string1 = [len, type, max]
string2 = ['hello', 5, [1,3,7]]
for func, param in zip(string1, string2):
    func(param)
```

Output

```
5
<class 'int'>
7
```

Also note that in your list of functions you should not add `()` to the end of the function because you will *call* the function if you do so. Just leave the function name itself (see the above `string1` list for example).

For your code the loop would look like

```
for each, every in zip(string2, string1):
    m.select(each)
    every(each)
```